# Filter list based on other cell without advanced filter

Tags: excel

Hello I have a list with a data validation list (0 & 1)

```
A  0
B  1
C  1
D  0
```

I am creating a button so that every time I click on it generates a random list of the Names based on the True statements (1s) without repeating them and eliminating the False statements (0s).

Something like this:

```
A  0   -->   B
B  1         C
C  1
D  0
```

I was able to create the button and make the names to not repeat themselves but I am missing on how to filter them or eliminating the False statements.

```
I used =IF() for the True and False statements
I used =RAND() for the repetition filter  
I used =INDEX() for the creation of the list
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter data based on condition. You can have a try on following.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$4)/($B$1:$B$4=1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Harun24HR I tried, but is returning me blank spaces only

Comment: I have seen the output in screenshot.  May be you are missing anything in formula.