# Excel delete blank rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delete-row

I want to pull information from one table to another, in such a way that if a particular cell does not meet a certain definition - the information will not pass. I did this using the IF function so that if it does not meet the definition the cell remains empty

`IF(K10>21,K5,"")`

I want the new table to automatically delete the blank rows - or alternatively not move in the first place (if the required condition is not met).

I have tried the **"go to special"** option but did not solve the problem since the table is constantly updated. Is there a suitable formula so that the cell deletion is performed automatically each time the table is updated?

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function to pull data from first table to second table automatically excluding blanks. `Filter()` function is available in `Office 365`

Comment: hi! thx for the answer. im using excel 2013 :/ also the first table dont have blanks, they appear only in the second table and only in cases where IF conditions are not met

Comment: You are only using `IF(K10>21,K5,"")` this formula?

Comment: So, you have an external data source. You want data from that source to be copied into an Excel sheet, but in case a part of the data does not meet a certain condition, you don't want to see it in Excel. In order to do that, you copy all the data into Excel, and you remove the obsolete data afterwards. Isn't there a way to avoid that data being copied into Excel? What kind of external data source are we talking about and how to you copy it into Excel?

Comment: Have a look on this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403833/filter-list-based-on-other-cell-without-advanced-filter/62403911#62403911)

Comment: harun24HR hi! :) yep only this one, tried to figure out if there is any way to pull only cells that meet the condition, and pass the one that not - By using IF, im not sure that is possible  - I thought about tring to do so using substitute formula, ill let u know if it worked! :) At the same time, in case it does not work, I try to think about the possibility of deleting the empty cells (Those that are irrelevant) after they have passed